# Complicated Minimal Ubuntu Question - i3, GLX, OpenGL, Gnome, and X

Tags: 17.04, ubuntu-minimal

I realize that I am not supposed to ask tech support questions here, at least when others ask it gets blasted. But I have a very Ubuntu specific question. Please don't judge me too hard.

I'm a big fan of /r/unixporn and minimal builds. I also currently love i3. But, Ubuntu is my best friend and favorite distro. So I usually build off of the minimal (mini.iso) or Ubuntu Server. Lately I've been using the mini.iso.

I have a pretty newish computer. But that shouldn't matter for my question.

Let me lay out my steps for you. Starting with the minimal build, I have 238 packages. Pretty sick. So I proceed to build the system I want with network-manager, i3, nvidia-375, xorg, and xserver-xorg. This allows me to exec i3 and then startx and get i3. This is where the problems are.

i3 doesn't start any OpenGL environment by itself. I install mesa-utils and mesa-common-dev and that doesn't start anything either. When I do glxinfo in i3 it just says could not find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig. When I start steam it says openglx extension not supported by display.

I know, i3 is just a window manager. But my extent of linux and Ubuntu knowledge are running out.

If I install gnome-core, or gnome and gnome-shell, and reboot into i3 this problem disappears. Its like gnome installs something and runs something that I can't track down. But when gnome installs it, obviously, installs like 1000 packages with it, and that is (kind of) against what I'm going for.

When I remove gnome / gnome-core / gnome-shell, and then autoremove other packages, it DOES NOT break i3, it still starts the OpenGL "whatever it is I need" and that is cool. But I still have a ton of gnome packages that the system is using and did not autoremove. I'm trying to get down under 1000. My best is 1012 packages.

I know, I know, this is stupid. I am silly. Its just something I want to do. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

output of dpkg -l xserver-xorg | grep '^ii'

```
    ii  xserver-xorg                   1:7.7+19ubuntu1                 amd64        X.Org X server
    ii  xserver-xorg-core              2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1               amd64        Xorg X server - core server
    ii  xserver-xorg-input-all         1:7.7+19ubuntu1                 amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
    ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput    0.25.0-0ubuntu1                 amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom       1:0.34.0-0ubuntu2               amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-legacy            2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1               amd64        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-all         1:7.7+19ubuntu1                 amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu      1.3.0-0ubuntu1                  amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati         1:7.9.0-0ubuntu1                amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev       1:0.4.4-1build6                 amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel       2:2.99.917+git20170309-0ubuntu1 amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau     1:1.0.14-0ubuntu1               amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl         0.1.5-2build1                   amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon      1:7.9.0-0ubuntu1                amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa        1:2.3.4-1build3                 amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware      1:13.2.1-1build1                amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

Comment: Tech support is what we're for you, you've probably just seen people asking very broad or unclear questions. Because we would close those, but as you can see from [the site rules](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), tech support is what we're here for. Though you must understand that we are all just volunteers and do this in our spare time.

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -l xserver-xorg* | grep '^ii'` in the two cases? in particular, does your minimal + i3wm install pull in `xserver-xorg-video-fbdev`

Comment: add output for steeldriver

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer.

These packages, specifically xorg and nvidia, fail to create 2 files:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf
```

The following are the contents of my files, for those of you running optimus systems with hybrid graphics. For those searching, I am running a G551, aka Asus ROG GL551 etc... with Nvidia 960m

So here is how you fix it.

You need those two files. Here are mine:

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

`/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf`

```
start on (starting lightdm
          or starting gdm
          or starting kdm
          or starting xdm
          or starting lxdm)
task
exec gpu-manager --log /var/log/gpu-manager.log
```